# conditionally displaying rows based on values in next row - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with few columns. I have a column which has numeric data. Eg:

```
1
2
3
5
4
4
```

I need to display row pertaining to that column based on value in the next row. I need fetch the rows for which the subsequent row is having even number.In the above example, I need to display 1 ,5 and 4.Is there a way to do it using SQL? I am using oracle database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle lead Analytical function can be used.

[Oracle Lead Analytical Function](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LagLeadAnalyticFunctions.php)

Comment: Thank you very much Nitin!! I presume in my case , I will have to use Lead function in where clause and check if the reminder is 0 when divided by 2. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
select COLUMN from 
(select COLUMN, case when mod(lead(COLUMN) over (order by COLUMN),2)=0 then 1 else 0 end CONTROL 
from YOURTABLE t) 
where CONTROL=1
```

Just change the COLUMN to your column name and YOURTABLE to your table name.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the values into a list and do the logic in the code. This is faster than doing fancy stuff in a query. It is also probably more understandable.